# append multiple queries into single and pass it in go-elasticsearch newboolquery for search

Tags: go, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to perform a advance elasticsearch in my chat application which is written in go. So, I have used go-elasticsearch to perform general search using elastic search in my chat application.
for advance elasticsearch I need three query builder/raw query builder that contains `filter queries, not filter, excludeterms`. like in `filterqueries` I have append multiple newtermqueries based on condition. After making these three queries I want to pass it into newboolquery function to perform must, should, must_not like, `elasticsearch.addmust(filter queries)` , `elasticsearch.should(not filter)` etc.
the problem is I have tried both library `olivere` and `go-elasticsearch` for it but didn't succeed. I think I am doing something wrong. can anyone help me?